# Air Purifier Circuit Mod Help

Tags: reverse-engineering, appliances

I have an air purifier I would like to modify the PCB to an always on state at high setting when plugged in.  This would allow me to control the device with and Amazon Echo compatible smart plug.

Important switches on the board

SW2 - Power on the unit which is initially in an off state.

SW1 - Cycle through fan speeds which is initially in the "Auto" state. 4 presses gets you to High, the 5th press back to "Auto".  "Auto" works based on a dust sensor.

SW1 and SW2 are labeled in the PCB screenshots below:

[image: front]

[image: back]

Thanks in advance for any tips or guidance for this project.

Comment: This will probably be closed as off-topic because it is not an Engineering *design* question but is rather about modifying a consumer product for which engineering information is not available.  If you want to approach it on your own, you should try to figure out how the circuit works.  But if this is a high voltage ion-type purifier, safety issues mean you should probably not attempt the project at all.

Comment: 100% on topic: except when designing these products ***or modifying their electronics for other uses***

Comment: @Passerby - you are mistaken, modification is only on topic when there is sufficient detail to approach it in an engineering manner.  Since no detail of the circuit implementation is given (only the effects achieved by its operation), that is not the case here.

Comment: @ChrisStratton no worries on closing, thought I would give it a shot and don't have much experience asking questions on stack. There is a starting place for everyone.

Comment: This is the case here. The circuit board and how it works is all you need to know to answer it. Like both myself and Tony have.

Comment: The firmware on this board is NOT going to let you go outside of its programmed behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to defeat the auto control method and have some personal need to control it remotely and defeat all the uC functions for the sensor and switches.  This implies a steady state operation and can be monitored on the connector CN1.  If you measure the voltages on each pin for each level (after you locate the 0V reference pin on the PIC processor. )

Then you can toss the board and just use jumpers to make connections on CN1 to enable the fan at full speed and ionizer all the time.

But I am not sure of the value of doing this unless the noise of the fan keeps you awake at night.  Then I would look at a better fan or a better quality air filter.

Comment: We only use this air purifier as a white noise fan at night and would it be awesome to ask Alexa or schedule it via Alexa to turn on and off.  Thanks for the tips!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a microcontroller to press the buttons for you when power comes on after a few seconds.

You can do this electronically with transistors or optocouplers across the two switches, or electro-mechanically with relays, or a non-interfering mechanical method of using solenoids or servos to physically press the buttons, so no internal modification is needed. Example:

[image]

As its using a microchip Pic microcontroller already, it's likely a 5V control panel and should be easy to do.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look and leaving your thoughts. This gives me some idea on where to look next.

Comment: You can't use either transistors or optocouplers without *understanding how the circuit works* - which is what is critically missing from the question to disqualify it from this site.  And even automated button pushing may be challenging to accomplish reliably without more detail of how the circuit/firmware responds or how to monitor its current state.  This is a general suggestion in response to an incomplete question, both lacking the specificity for which SE sites are reserved.

Comment: Uhhuh. That's why relays and servos are mentioned. Because there is multiple ways of doing it. And you just want to be pedantic rule lawyer about a clearly on topic question. "Challenging to accomplish" gtfo.

Comment: Especially when the clear circuit board picture shows them to be simple active low switches.

Answer (score 0):

Of the 8 pins on CN1:

- two are unused
- two are used for power and ground
- one is connected only to the buzzer; probably another supply voltage
- the remaining three are connected directly to the PIC, so they are stricly logic-level controls and/or status.

It would be worth exploring what is happening on these pins during normal operation, using an oscilloscope.

My guess would be that one is used to turn on the high voltage, possibly using PWM if the voltage is variable.

Another is used to control the fan, again using PWM to vary the speed.

The third might be a filter status sensor (or this function could be handled by simply counting total run time).

If you just want the fan to run full speed, you could simply set this board aside and jumper some of the pins on the plug that goes onto CN1 together. Or pop the PIC out of its socket(!) and do it there.

If you really want to get fancy, take an hour to draw the full schematic of the board (it really isn't complicated at all) and program your own PIC to do exactly what you want.